# DVD RW+ Not showing up

Tags: dvd

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 on a Toshiba Satellite Pro A120 and my built in DVD Drive is not opening any cd/dvd/dvd rw that am trying to play on them. the drive seems to be mounted and recongnized:

Output of sudo lshw: 
...

```
 <$>  *-cdrom
                description: DVD-RAM writer
                product: DVD-RAM UJ-841S
                vendor: MATSHITA
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
                logical name: /dev/cdrom
                logical name: /dev/cdrw
                logical name: /dev/dvd
                logical name: /dev/dvdrw
                logical name: /dev/sr0
                version: 1.40
                capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
                configuration: ansiversion=5 status=ready
              *-medium
                   physical id: 0
                   logical name: /dev/cdrom
<$>
```

and the disk seems to start but hang with the dvd drive LED solid amber.... 
the output of

```
<$> jun@jun-Satellite-Pro-A120:~$ dmesg | grep "sr0" 

[679396.184901] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] Unhandled sense code
[679396.184910] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[679396.184920] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[679396.184931] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0]  Add. Sense: Id CRC or ECC error
[679396.184942] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[679396.184965] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 0
[679396.184975] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 0
[679396.184984] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 1
[679396.184990] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 2
[679396.184996] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 3
[679396.185002] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 4
[679396.185008] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 5
[679396.185014] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 6
[679396.185020] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 7
[679396.185031] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 8
[679396.185038] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 9
[679396.185070] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] unaligned transfer
[679396.185108] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] unaligned transfer
<$>
```

Can someone help me through this? tired of moving around with an external dvd drive.

Thanks